# Routing in the React stepper

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-router

In material UI the common stepper is there, I want to make it global to fix the URL. So that if we want to reload the page it should stay on the same page.

**Picture:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgiEH.png

In the picture above, common structure and state are followed with an update and stepper from 1 to 2 so in step 1. I want the perfect URL for that same as it for step 2 as follows

Comment: Can you update your question to provide a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for what you've tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.